# Is the Galois group of a given polynomial always a subgroup of the Klein-$4$ group?

Tags: galois-theory

Let $f(x) = (x^2-ax+b)(x^2-cx+d)$ be a separable polynomial with rational coefficients.
Is it true, that its Galois group over the rationals is always a subgroup of the Klein four group $C_2 \times C_2$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $K_1,K_2$ be Galois extension of given factors of $f(x)$ over $\mathbb{Q}$. They are at most degree $2$. (See what happens if one of them is of degree $1$; i.t. $\mathbb{Q}$).

If both are degree $2$ extensions, consider their join in some algebraic closure (it is degree $\leq 4$ extension). Thus the Galois extension of $f(x)$ is inside this extension $K_1K_2$.

If $K_1=K_2$ then $K_1K_2=K_1$ is the Galois extension of $f(x)$ of degree $2$.

If $K_1\neq K_2$, then the Galois extension $K_1K_2$ of $f(x)$ has (at least) two subfields; correspondingly, Galois group (of order $4$) should contain two (at least) subgroups; what it should be?